# What is the difference between alphabetic and numeric types in the CSS symbols() function?

Tags: css, function

Can you explain me please, What is the difference between of that two types in css symbols() function? When I try separately each of them, I has'nt seen any difference, only one - numbering start from 0 and first symbol doesn't show first in the list.

```css
div {
  margin: 70px 70px;
}

ol {
  list-style: symbols(numeric "○" "●" "□")
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `numeric`, the symbols represent the digits of a number system, where the number of symbols represents the base. The list starts at `1`, and when it runs out of symbols, it continues to `10`.

```css
ol {
  list-style: symbols(numeric "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

For `alphabetic`, the list is constructed in the same way, but without the assumption that the first symbol represents `0`. When the list runs out of symbols, it continues with `00` instead of `10`.

```css
ol {
  list-style: symbols(alphabetic "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[symbols() - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols())

Comment: thank you very much for your help....